# Not getting the required output while scraping a feedback website using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

This is the code I used to scrape the website

```
import scrapy
class DellLatitudeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dell_latitude'
    allowed_domains = ['www.dell.com/community']
    
    def start_request(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.dell.com/community/Latitude/bd-p/Latitude?ref=lithium_menu', callback=self.parse, headers='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5060.114 Safari/537.36')

    def parse(self, response):
        for activity in response.xpath("//table[@class='lia-list-wide']"):
            yield {
                'board': 'Laptops',
                'sub board': 'Latitude',
                'title': activity.xpath("//a[@class='page-link lia-link-navigation lia-custom-event']/text()").get(),
                'url': activity.xpath("//a[@class='page-link lia-link-navigation lia-custom-event']/@href").get()

            }
```

Initially, I got an error which I corrected by adding the User-Agent but now, when I crawl the file, it says 0 pages crawled and nothing else. What can be missing in the code?

Here's how I'm getting the output.

```
2022-07-08 17:38:01 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2022-07-08 17:38:01 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-07-08 17:38:01 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-07-08 17:38:01 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-07-08 17:38:01 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-07-08 17:38:01 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.005837,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 8, 12, 8, 1, 807968),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 8, 12, 8, 1, 802131)}
2022-07-08 17:38:01 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `headers` parameter should be a `dict` that maps header names to header values, shouldn't it? e.g.

`headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5060.114 Safari/537.36'}`

Comment: Adding them didn't get me the results.